# Random order numbers in the opencart

Tags: opencart

I have a website in opencart and currently its running very good but the problem is the random order number one order number is 3361 and the second order number is 3381 for the same day. I can't understand where is all those 20 order goes. Please provide me the method how to solve this problem so that i can get the order number in serial.

Answer (score 1):

The truth is:

OpenCart creates new order anytime the "Order Confirm" page is displayed. This is the last step in ordering process after which the order is confirmed and pending and emails are sent.

However anytime on confirm page a user hits page refresh or goes back to change something and comes back on confirm page (step) again a new order ID is generated (in other words, a new order is created while throwing that older one away).

This is why sometimes between two real orders the ID is not continuous - but if You opened up Your phpMyAdmin and looked at the `orders` table You would find out that there are IDs continuously used by orders that are unfinished thus not visible in administration.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can i be able to solve the problem here.

Comment: @PawanKumar I do not see any problem here. It is not essential to have the order's IDs in continuous order. At least cannot think of a situation where it could be essential. Anyway, it could be overcome by creating `temp_orders` table (copy of `orders` table) and editing the `Order` model - when an order is created it is created in a `temp_orders` and after it is confirmed it is **copied** into `orders` table without the ID column.

Comment: In admin->sales->orders you can filter for an order status of 'Missing Orders' - here you will see orders placed, but not paid for, as generated by the above.

Answer (score 0):

I think opencart allocate an order number to each client when they plug an item to cart.
Then if the client doesn't finalize the purchase and clear the cart that number is simply forgotten.

Comment: That is not entirely true... It does not happen on product adding to a cart - that would be pretty silly.